# how to plot edgelist file as a network in networkx

Tags: social-networking, networkx

I have an edgelist file. How to plot this edgelist as a network in networkx? I need to visualize it as a network graph like nodes and edges. Can anyone know this?

Answer (score 2):

The basic pattern works like this:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [3]: G = nx.Graph()  # create empty graph

In [4]: G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(4,5)]) # or use nx.read_edgelist("path")

In [5]: nx.draw(G)

In [6]: plt.show()
```

If you are reading the edgelist from a file, then use: `G=nx.read_edgelist("test.edgelist")` and substitute the path to your edgelist in step 4. More in the documentation on [`read_edgelist()`](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html#networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist)